# PHP: How to know if a date is in the current month?

Tags: php, date

I need to know if a date is in the current month.

Examples:

- If the date is 2018-**06**-30 and current month is June (06), then **true**.
- If the date is 2018-**07**-30 and current month is June (06), then **false**.

I have a list of dates with more than 1000 dates and I want to show or colorize only the dates that belongs to a current month.

Comment: `2018-06-31` doesn't exist, do you care about that? `n` with http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php could be a solution if you are really working with dates. Possible solution https://3v4l.org/GVR17

Comment: It would help the question if you clarified that the strings are always valid dates.

Answer (score 11):

You can do it all on one line. Basically convert the date in question to a PHP time, and get the month.

```
date('m',strtotime('2018-06-30' )) == date('m');
```

Using the `date()` function, if you pass in only the format, it'll assume the current date/time. You can pass in a second optional variable of a `time()` object to use in lieu of the current date/time.

Comment: It is `Unix timestamp`, not `PHP time`.

Comment: You are correct, I should have clarified that. The PHP `time()` function returns a `Unix Timestamp`

Comment: I should add that you might want to also compare the year. For your purposes, June of this year may or may not be the same as June of last year.

Answer (score 2):

I hope this helps -

```
$date = "2018-07-31";

if(date("m", strtotime($date)) == date("m"))
{
    //if they are the same it will come here
}
else
{
    // they aren't the same
}
```

Comment: This is probably a typo but the comparison of the `date("Y-m-d")` is comparing it to `2018-06-26` and not just the current month. To only get the current month, use `date('m')`

Comment: Yes, it is :D Good eye!

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative you could use a [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) and for the format use for example the [n](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) to get the  numeric representation of a month without leading zeros and use `Y` to get the full numeric representation of a year in 4 digits.

```
$d = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', '2018-06-30');
$today = new DateTime();
if($d->format('n') === $today->format('n') && $d->format('Y') === $today->format('Y')) {
    echo "Months match and year match";
}
```

[Test](https://3v4l.org/mGQFW)

Answer (score 0):

PHP doesn't implement a date type. If you are starting with a date/time and you know that your you are only dealing with a single timezone, AND you mean you want the current month *in the curent year*

```
$testdate=strtotime('2018-06-31 12:00'); // this will be converted to 2018-07-01
if (date('Ym')==date('Ym', $testdate)) {
   // current month
} else {
   // not current month
}
```